# ES6 - Where is it better to initialize a member - parent class or derived class?

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6, constructor

I am trying to figure out if there is a better practice for initializing class members of derived classes in ES6 - in the child or the parent, and why?

For example:

**Option 1:**

```
class AbstractAnimal {
   constructor() {
       this.voice = null;
   }

   makeVoice() {
      this.voice.make(); 
   }
}

class Dog extends AbstractAnimal {
   constructor() {
       super();
       this.voice = new Bark();
   }

   onSeeFriend() {
       this.makeVoice();
   }
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
class AbstractAnimal {
   constructor(voice) {
       this.voice = voice;
   }

   makeVoice() {
      this.voice.make(); 
   }
}

class Dog extends AbstractAnimal {
   constructor() {
       super(new Bark());
   }

   onSeeFriend() {
       this.makeVoice();
   }
}
```

Obviously, there are pro's and cons in both methods.
The first options spreads the initialization of members around, which makes it harder to trace. While the second option will bubble everything up to one place, but than you could end up with huge constructors taking a lot of arguments.

Would appreciate it if I could hear your thought about this. 
Thanks!

Comment: What is `this.voice;` in Option 1 supposed to do?

Comment: It's the voice of the Animal. Every Animal has one. Every Animal uses it deferentially. Yet the base class does make the voice the same way for all the children. 
The point was to show that this.voice is something that both the parent and the child should and can be aware of

Comment: But just writing that as a statement doesn't do anything. Why is that in the constructor?

Comment: It should be something like `this.voice = <something>;`

Comment: Maybe you meant `this.voice = null;` to give it a default initial value.

Comment: Oh, Well, that is just for better understanding of the class structure, since voice is something basic that every animal should have. It could technically work without it.

Comment: Well, now it's the equivalent of this.voice = undefined. is there a reason why this.voice = null should be better?

Comment: If you're going to assign something explicitly, `null` seems more appropriate; `undefined` should be reserved just for variables that haven't been assigned at all.

Comment: Anyway, this question is mostly opinion-based, so it's not really on-topic for [so]. I'd go with #2 because it makes it clear that every animal has to have a voice.

Comment: [softwareengineering.se] might be a better place to ask a "best practices" question like this.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I will try there too.

Answer (score 0):

As this question is an opinion poll I would just like to point out that there is a *third way*, as always in JS: Mixins

**Pro**s: allows abstracting the initialisation away to a *third* `class`; `AbstractAnimal` is truly abstract
**Con**s: can be hard to justify for simple cases such as a barking `Dog`

```js
class AbstractAnimal {
  makeVoice() { this.voice.make(); }
}
const Barking = Base => class extends Base {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.voice = new Bark();
  }
}
class Dog extends Barking(AbstractAnimal) {
  onSeeFriend() { this.makeVoice(); }
}


class Bark { make() { console.log('Woof'); } }
new Dog().onSeeFriend();
```